# How can I make a list view with 4 columns use two zones or columns on a wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-server, column, format

I have a list view that contains 4 columns. The list is being shown on a wiki page. I want to wrap the list so that it is not so long. By wrap, I mean split the number of rows in half and show the first half on the left side of the screen and the second half on the right side. Something like this where columns are A, B, C, and D

A B C D  spaces   A B C D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to achieve this in the wiki page.

As a workaround, you could use web part page to display the list on the left and right sides of a page.